# Retrying SQL Azure requests with strongly typed datasets

Tags: sql-server, azure, strongly-typed-dataset

We recently started testing an ASP.NET application in Microsoft Azure with a SQL Azure database. We get infrequent timeouts and lost connections. We now understand this is the nature of a cloud-based database and use of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block is the recommended solution. However, this seems to require that your code create the connection and issue the access request. Since we are using strongly typed datasets this logic is hidden inside the Fill(), for example, in the code generated for the dataset. We have business object units that actually invoke the methods within the generated code so we have a place to put retry logic but would rather not put identical code in hundreds of places.

Is there any way to use the TFHAB in this situation or a way to incorporate retry logic in a general way that doesn't require so much code?

Comment: You don't have to use the default connection with the tableadapter - you can manage connections in your own code and pass them to the TA's connection property.

Comment: Good point. We already have a class that does that. I'll investigate using the ReliableSqlConnection that way.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I have a static class called TransientError containing the following two static methods (I borrowed most of the code off MSDN):

```
internal static void Try(DbContext context)
{
    int wait = 800;
    bool retry = true;
    while (retry)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("declare @i int;", con))
                {
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            Clear(context);
            Thread.Sleep(wait);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            retry = false;
        }
        // break after we reach 6.4 secs (for a total as 12 secs)
        if (wait == 6400)
        {
            retry = false;
        }
        wait = wait * 2;
    }
}
private static void Clear(DbContext context)
{
    // This is a client side operation so won't cause an exception
    // with a server side error.
    // If it does fail, probably should throw!
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
    }
}
```

This solves the problem of a transient network error leaving a 'broken' (and unreusable) connection in the connection pool.

I'm using Linq, and each of my access methods looks like this:

```
public StructureElement ForId(int elementId)
{
    TransientError.Try(this.context);
    StructureElement element = (from se in this.context.StructureElements
                                where se.Id == elementId
                                select se).FirstOrDefault<StructureElement>();
    return element;
}
```

Test the connection with TransientError.Try (which clears the ConnectionPool if there's a problem, and then run the Linq query. If that has a problem, then the caller's exception handling takes over.

Other ways of doing it are possible - calling TransientError only if the actual Linq errors etc etc.

It's been in production for about a year now with no problems.

Comment: This doesn't directly address the actual situation (strongly typed datasets) but does provide some ideas to incorporate into the solution.

Comment: The actual return type and how the data is got is fairly irrelevant, I think. I could have coded up a new way of applying it, but it would be rather a ,lot of work. However, I you showed what you had coded I could have copied it and showed how I would have applied the technique. Still, if this helps that's good. Cheers -